# Recursive relationship in Django: get all the interrelated records from each record

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-managers

I have this model for a tune:

```
class MsTune(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ms = models.ForeignKey(Manuscript, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="mstunes")
    concordances = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True)
```

I have many manuscripts (ms), and the same tune might appear in more than one manuscript. What I want to do, with that `concordances` field, is link all the similar tunes. This works, in part. The Django administration back-end allows me to select many tunes to be linked to the current one I'm editing:

[image]

The problem is that I'd like to see ALL the tunes I've linked in EACH of the tune. For instance, in the example above, Mary Scott... should list all three tunes (Courante, Almain, Hopetounsetc...); Courante should list the other three (Mary Scott, Almain, Hopetoun's). Right now they only show the one from which editing page I've added them. What am I missing? Do I have to create a new `concordances` model?

**PS**

Specifying `symmetrical=True` doesn't help.

**Better explanation of what I want to achieve**

If I have these tunes:

```
tune_1
tune_1a
tune_1b
tune_2
```

Right now I'm getting this:

```
tune_1:
concordances.all: tune_1a, tune_1b

tune_1a:
concordances.all: tune_1

tune_1b:
concordances.all: tune_1
```

I want this:

```
tune_1:
concordances.all: tune_1a, tune_1b

tune_1a:
concordances.all: tune_1, tune_1b

tune_1b:
concordances.all: tune_1, tune_1a
```

**Partial solution with intermediary model**

Let's say I use an intermediary model:

```
class MsTune(models.Model):

    related = models.ManyToManyField('MsTune', through='Concordance', blank=True)
[...]

class Concordance(models.Model):
    tune = models.ManyToManyField(MsTune)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

How do I then access the list of interrelated tunes in a template where I'm displaying the details of a specific tune?

```
{% for concordance in tune.concordance_set.all %} {{ concordance__mstune_id }}{% endfor %}
```

Doesn't output anything; and `[...]{{ concordance }}[...]` outputs the name of the concordance, not the title of each tune.

Accessing `{{ tune.concordances }}` gives me a `'ManyToManyField' object has no attribute '_m2m_reverse_name_cache'` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by creating a different model:

```
class Concordance(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    tunes = models.ManyToManyField(MsTune, related_name="concordances")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```